# How to draw properly image on bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawimage

I have some *image (.png)* it has resolution **96 x 96** and size **100 x 200**. It is **myImageLoadedFromFile**.

And I need to draw properly over it some other images (**anotherImage**).

I use *Photoshop* to detect coordinates of X and Y. *Photoshop* shows some strange coordinates like X = 1.5f and Y= 1,8f when I use mouse to plan where I have to draw that little image. But what I have got is that all images I draw are at the left top corner.

It seems like I have to use different way to know which coordinates I have to use to do it properly.

Any clue how to do it? Which Tool is possible to use to get proper coords. using mouse?

Here my C# code

```
 var bitmap  = new Bitmap(myImageLoadedFromFile);  
 using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
 {
     g.DrawImage(anotherImage, new PointF(1.5f, 1,8f));
     g.Flush();
 }
```

Comment: To make your live easier, right click on the rulers in Photoshop (Ctrl+R if they're not showing) and change them over to pixels

Comment: @ChrisHaas It seems like you are right, brother! Hahahaa Please put it like an answer, man! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change Photoshop's default units from points to pixels. With any document open just right-click on the rules (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> if they're not showing already).

You can also get to this through the menus at Edit -> Preferences -> Units & Rulers